# Starting a New ASP.Net Core 2.0 Project with Identity using "dotnet new"

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

How do you start a new ASP.Net Core 2.0 Project with Identity?

"dotnet new mvc" does not include Account or Manage models/controllers/views.

Comment: dotnet new mvc --auth Individual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
```

See [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x).

Comment: Great idea if you want a project named after your username.  How about including the actual name of the project.

Comment: @RyanDines, no, it will be name of folder, from which you run

Comment: This is tech that I use every day and yes, your folder will be named that, in addition to a bunch of other naming dependencies that are hard to change.  So maybe instead of writing "See tutorial", you actually run and test code that you answer about.

Comment: @RyanDines, yes, I actually ran it and got what I wanted. It's just minimal example without any unnecessary options.

Comment: Okay, sorry for being mean about it.  I just found it hard to change the name once the project is already made, actually thats true of every framework I've used, so many dependencies on that initial name, so wanted to give people a heads up.

Answer (score -2):

Say you wanted to call your site seniordevops.com, you might go:

```
dotnet new mvc -o SeniorDevops --auth Individual
```

Builds a directory for you with an initial sqlite migration.  I like replacing the sqlite DB with PostgreSQL and rerunning the migrations at this point, you could also go SQL-server by adding this at the end: `-uld`

Comment: domain name has no relation to the project name

Comment: Some projects might never have a domain name if you don't tie them to DNS.  It is pretty standard though if your building a website to call the project name by the future domain name.  Tell you what Alex, you can name your projects 'foo' when you're developing for 'bar.com', but I prefer a similar naming convention.